# An Altered List

Tags: knowledge, wordplay

The following list of items has been altered. They all use some form of wordplay originating from the item, with some being very literal and straightforward, while others are obscure and challenging. You need not solve all of the items (but congrats if you do!), the answer is the category of the original items. Good luck!

- ">->o"
- A hose
- A test question
- Art
- The NFL (if everyone wore red helmets)
- Dirt on a hand?
- A political TV show filmed at Charles University
- 0.0697564737
- Two "Sonic the Hedgehog" characters
- .- / -... .- -. -..
- Harry, Hermione, & Ron
- A typical LEGO minifigure head

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a list of:

> stories by Arthur Conan Doyle featuring his detective, **[Sherlock Holmes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canon_of_Sherlock_Holmes)**.

The clues should be interpreted as follows:

">->o"

> Possibly *The Adventure of the Crooked Man*, since the symbols form the shape of a man lying down. (Alternatively, he may be *Creeping* instead, since the quotation marks might suggest movement lines...)

A hose

> *The Adventure of the Empty House* - since if we 'empty' the word HOUSE by removing its middle letter, we get HOSE!

A test question

> *The Adventure of the Missing Three-Quarter* (sounds like a question in a mathematics test)

Art

> Possibly *The Adventure of the Retired Colourman*, since a 'colourman' is an art supply dealer.

The NFL (if everyone wore red helmets)

> *The Red-Headed League* (the 'L' in [NFL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Football_League) stands for 'League')

Dirt on a hand?

> *The Adventure of the Engineer's Thumb* (which would potentially be covered in grease)
>  <sub>(The OP reveals in comments that their intention was actually *The Adventure of the Second Stain*, which might sound like the *second hand* of a clock is dirty...)</sub>

A political TV show filmed at Charles University

> *A [Scandal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scandal_(TV_series)) in Bohemia* (Charles University is found in the historic region of [Bohemia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bohemia) in modern-day Czechia)
>  <sub>(Thanks to @JerryDean in comments)</sub>

0.0697564737

> *The Sign of the Four* - this number is $sin(4)$ i.e. the 'sine of 4'.

Two "Sonic the Hedgehog" characters

> *The Adventure of [Silver](https://sonic.fandom.com/wiki/Silver_the_Hedgehog) [Blaze](https://sonic.fandom.com/wiki/Blaze_the_Cat)*

.- / -... .- -. -..

> *The Adventure of the Speckled Band* - the Morse code decoded spells 'A BAND'.

Harry, Hermione, & Ron

> *The Adventure of the Three Students* (Harry Potter, Hermione Granger and Ron Weasley are all students together at Hogwarts in [the books by J.K. Rowling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harry_Potter))

A typical LEGO minifigure head

> *The Adventure of the Yellow Face* (traditionally the colour of LEGO minifigure heads)

Comment: Wow, that was fast!
I will point out that rot13("Qveg ba n unaq?" jnf zrnag gb or Gur Frpbaq Fgnva (nf va gur frpbaq unaq ba n pybpx)), but that does also make sense.
Good luck with the rest of them!

Comment: @WoomyRogue Ah, okay - I'm still thinking about the others though... :)

Comment: "A political TV show filmed at Charles University" may be rot13("N Fpnaqny va Oburzvn"), since rot13(Gur Xvat bs Oburzvn jrag sebz Centhr gb frr Fureybpx Ubyzrf, naq Puneyrf Havirefvgl vf xabja uvfgbevpnyyl nf gur Havirefvgl bs Centhr.) It's a pretty wild guess, though.

Comment: @JerryDean Ah, you're right! The TV show is just *Scandal* and Charles University is in Czechia which is formerly Bohemia - good thinking :)

Comment: @Stiv Thanks! As for the hose one, I have a hypothesis: rot13(N flabalz sbe "ubfr" vf "cvcr", juvpu vf cerggl fvzvyne gb "cvc", naq pbhyq or ersreevat gb Svir Benatr Cvcf. Ubjrire, V guvax guvf zvtug abg or pbeerpg, nf vg fnvq "n ubfr" vafgrnq bs "svir ubfrf" be fbzrguvat yvxr gung.)